# ssl.wrap_socket alert SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE

Tags: python-2.7, sockets

I'm trying to establish a secure socket connection in Python, but i had a handshake failure.This is what i've been trying:

```
import socket
import ssl

# CREATE SOCKET
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# WRAP SOCKET
wrappedSock = ssl.wrap_socket(s, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23, ciphers="ADH-AES256-SHA")

# CONNECT AND PRINT REPLY
wrappedSock.connect(('www.google.com.hk', 443))
wrappedSock.send('''GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com.hk
Connection: close
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.75 Safari/537.36
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
''')

buf = wrappedSock.recv(1024)
while len(buf):
    print buf
    buf = wrappedSock.recv(1024)
```

**Alert error is**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    wrappedSock.connect(('www.google.com.hk', 443))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 876, in connect
    self._real_connect(addr, False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 867, in _real_connect
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 840, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:661)
```

**My environment is**:

```
Python 2.7.13
pyOpenSSL (16.2.0)
ndg-httpsclient (0.4.3)
pyasn1 (0.2.2)
pyasn1-modules (0.0.8)
```

I also tried "ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1" and it had the same error. Hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
wrappedSock = ssl.wrap_socket(... ciphers="ADH-AES256-SHA")
...
wrappedSock.connect(('www.google.com.hk', 443))
```

The server you are trying to access does not support the cipher you are specifying. Almost no server is supporting ADH ciphers since these don't authenticate the server and are thus open for easy man in the middle attacks.

It is unclear why you are trying to use specifically this cipher. But I recommend that you simply skip the `ciphers` argument so that it will use the default ciphers.

Comment: Thank you, this help me.

Comment: I have another question, how can i get cleartext from wrappedSock.recv()? Or how to decrypt data from wrappedSock.recv()?

Comment: @bi3g0: different questions should not be asked in a comment but as a different question. But as long as you call `recv` on the wrapped socket (`wrappedSock.recv`) and not the underlying non-wrapped socket (`s.recv`) you should get the already decrypted data.

Comment: @bi3g0: Note that you still need to send a proper request: your's is using a wrong line end and is missing the empty line at the end of the header. Also, what you might feel as encrypted data could actually be gzip compressed data since your request claims to accept these.

Comment: @ Steffen Ullrich  Thank you~